# How to find directories whose size is greater than 4K?

Tags: filesystems

When you have many files in one directory, the size of the directory file grows because it needs to store more entries. So, at some point it could look like this:

```
# ls -ldh /var/log
drwxr-xr-x 15 root root 94M Jun 14 10:44 /var/log
```

As you can see, instead of 4K size, there's 94M. Of course it's just an example, but according to [this infomation](https://superuser.com/a/142900/274760), the size doesn't shrink, even when you delete files. You have to recreate the directory and move the remaining files into it.

How can I find those directories whose size is larger than 4K?

Comment: The size of a directory is an implementation detail of each type of filesystem. Not all filesystems behave as you have described. For example, I believe Btrfs does not. Another example is xfs: although it doesn't usually shink directories, it does so if they become empty.

Comment: We can stick with ext4 only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find . -type d -size +4096c
```

Would report those directories larger than 4kiBs. It's the same as for regular files. For most file systems, *directories* (think of them as phone directories, a list of mappings between number and name, not *folders*) are exactly like regular files, it's just that their content has a specific format and is treated specially and only modified via dedicated APIs.